# double quote coin flip

Tags: python, double-quotes, coin-flipping

```
import random
input("You tossed a coin. Select 0 or 1\n" )
random_side = random.randint(0, 1)
if random_side == 1:
  print("Heads")
else:
  print("Tails")
```

when I use double quote in 1(if random_side == "1":). It gives me same output not random outcome.

Comment: Edit the question to explain what happens, what should happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the result of `random.randint` won't work because `randint` produces an integer value. You can tell the type of a value by calling the `type` function:

```
>>> type(random.randint(0, 1))
<class 'int'>
```

So, when comparing, you should do if `if random_side == 1:`. Alternatively, you could do `if random_side:` as Python will interpret a 0 as False and a 1 as  True.

As an aside, before using Python's random library, you should seed the random generator to ensure that you get reasonably random results. Failing to do so might result in the random number generator using the same values for each run. You can find relevant documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted your input to determine which side the coin flips, then you have to first:

1. store the input in a variable
2. since you want it to be an integer, ensure it is an integer
3. add it to the conditional

   coinFlip = int(input("You tossed a coin. Select 0 or 1\n"))

   if coinFlip == 1:
   print("Heads")
   else:
   print("Tails")

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way to choose heads or tails would be `random.choice()`. See below:

```
from random import choice
print(choice(['heads', 'tails'])) # Or assign this to a variable
```

Please read up on the random modules.